# Efeito de scroll indesejado

Tags: javascript, html, rolamento, materialize, aba

Estou usando os [tab do materialize](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html), a troca funciona normalmente, porém sempre que clico em alguma tab move a página para o topo, não sei o porquê, acredito que tenha a ver com o efeito de scroll suave, mas não tenho certeza

```html
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">


<div style='margin-top: 500px' id='tudo' class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s4"><a class='active' href="#minhas">Minhas</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#favoritas">Favoritas</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#publicas">Públicas</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- LISTA DE MINHAS -->
  <div class="row" id="minhas"></div>

  <!-- LISTA FAVORITAS -->
  <div class="row" id="favoritas"></div>

  <!-- LISTA PÚBLICAS -->
  <div class="row" id="publicas"></div>
</div>

<footer>
  <!-- Import JQuery.js -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Smooth scrolling effect -->
  <script>
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing');
      });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tabs').tabs();
    });
  </script>

  <!-- Import materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Você não quer que a página vá para o topo ao trocar de aba? Este é o efeito indesejado?

Comment: @guastallaigor porque essa tab fica no meio do html, onde é mostrado coisas diferentes dependendo da aba, fica muito ruim clicar no favoritos para ver seus favoritos e ser jogado para o topo e ter que rolar para baixo tudo de novo para ver o conteudo

Comment: Aham tranquilo, só queria confirmar se tinha entendido corretamente, vou tentar algo aqui sem tirar seu efeito de scroll suave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que estava causando o problema era a inicialização das tabs

```
$('.tabs').tabs();
```

Consegui resolver o problema adicionando uma classe aos links que não fazem parte das tabs e mudando o seletor do efeito de scroll suave para

```
$('a[href^="#"].link')...
```

Assim o efeito só é chamado nos links que tiverem a classe `link`

Comment: Não achei que a existência de outros links interferiria

Comment: Desculpa qualquer coisa, mas valorizo sua resposta (tanto que dei +1) e tu me ajudou retirando partes do efeito scroll que nem precisava, enquanto tu buscava a solução eu também fui fazendo mais uns testes a partir do que tu falava e acabei descobrindo o que causava o erro, depois tive essa ideia de adicionar uma classe, acho ela meio gambi, e por isso ainda quero deixar a pergunta aberta para ver se alguém descobre como resolver o problema sem ter que adicionar uma classe extra em todos os links âncoras

Comment: Tranquilo, se descobrir uma forma de resolver o problema menos gambiarrosa avisa ai :)

Comment: Na verdade não achei gambiarra não. Vc só segregou os links que lhe interessava para o caso. Acho correto.

Comment: Ter que adicionar uma classe a todos os itens âncoras para que o efeito de rolagem suave funcione, mesmo que não seja uma gambi, é no mínimo uma mão

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi o motivo do evento `click` estar dentro do evento `scroll`, por isso removi (deixei comentado com `//`).

Mas você pode resolver o problema pegando o `offset().top` do elemento clicado que contém a hash, desta forma:

```
'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top
```

Veja o código:

```html
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">


<div style='margin-top: 500px' id='tudo' class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s4"><a class='active' href="#minhas">Minhas</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#favoritas">Favoritas</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#publicas">Públicas</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- LISTA DE MINHAS -->
  <div class="row" id="minhas">minhas</div>

  <!-- LISTA FAVORITAS -->
  <div class="row" id="favoritas">favs</div>

  <!-- LISTA PÚBLICAS -->
  <div class="row" id="publicas">pubs</div>
</div>

<footer>
  <!-- Import JQuery.js -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Smooth scrolling effect -->
  <script>
//    $(document).scroll(function() {
      $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing');
//      });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tabs').tabs();
    });
  </script>

  <!-- Import materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Não manjo muito de JQuery peguei da internet e coloquei. Também não funcionou, se quiser dar uma olhada na página https://receitas-alpha.firebaseapp.com

Comment: Testei alterando isso também mas não funcionou, o que eu acho estranho é motivo para ir pro topo, o script do scroll deveria apenas tornar a rolagem devagar

Comment: Tente assim : `var $target = $(this).closest("li").is(".tab") ? $('a[href="'+target+'"]') : $(target);`

Comment: Então muda para `'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top`

Comment: Apague as linhas `var target = this.hash;`  e `var $target = $(target);`

Comment: Também não adiantou

Comment: Então seu problema está além da pergunta. A solução resolve apenas o problema das tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Eu apenas removi a instrução que jogava a página para cima e parece que deu certo. Tente fazer isso.

```html
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">


<div style='margin-top: 500px' id='tudo' class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s4"><a class='active' href="#minhas">Minhas</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#favoritas">Favoritas</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#publicas">Públicas</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- LISTA DE MINHAS -->
  <div class="row" id="minhas"></div>

  <!-- LISTA FAVORITAS -->
  <div class="row" id="favoritas"></div>

  <!-- LISTA PÚBLICAS -->
  <div class="row" id="publicas"></div>
</div>

<footer>
  <!-- Import JQuery.js -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Smooth scrolling effect -->
  <script>
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        // Removi a linha que vinha aqui
      });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tabs').tabs();
    });
  </script>

  <!-- Import materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Essa linha é o efeito de rolagem suave que não pode ser retirado porque é usado em outras partes do html